# How to test asynchronous behaviors using Ruby and Cucumber?

Tags: ruby, asynchronous, testing, cucumber

I’m starting a new automated test project using Ruby, Cucumber, Capybara and SitePrism. It's an opportunity to define a clean and easy to maintain architecture.
However there is already a challenge that I didn't find any elegant solution, it’s testing for asynchronous behaviors.

One of the many asynchronous behaviors that i have to test is email sending, after a sale is done, the system sends an email to the buyer, and i need to test if the email was sent correctly, however, the email sending is not immediately, it is put in a queue and it takes some time to execute (around 1-3 minutes).

The system uses a tool to, in a test environment, store the sent emails in a database. I'm accessing that database, searching for the email subject and asserting the recipients.

The scenario definition looks like this:

```
Scenario: Send sale email
Given I'm logged in as "send_sale_email"
When I make a sale
Then the system should send a sale confirmation email
```

And, on step_definitions:

```
Then "the system should send a sale confirmation email" do
  buyer_email = 'buyer_email@email.com'
  email_subject = "Sale confirmation #{@sale_number}"
  email_recipients = get_email_recipients(email_subject)
  expect email_recipients.to include(buyer_email)
end
```

But when the sale is done and the tests access the database, the email has not been sent yet, and there is no guarantee on when it is going to be sent. I made a way to retry from time to time, it works:

```
Then "the system should send a sale confirmation email" do
  buyer_email = 'buyer_email@email.com'
  email_subject = "Sale confirmation #{@sale_number}"
  sleep_time = 30
  max_retries = 6
  retry_count = 0
  begin
    email_recipients = get_sent_email_recipients(email_subject)
    expect(email_recipients).to include(buyer_email)
  rescue RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError => e
    if retry_count <= max_retries
      retry_count += 1
      sleep sleep_time
      retry
    end
    raise e
  end
end
```

That way it waits for around 3 minutes, but putting sleep in the tests does not look good, and there are multiple operations in the system like that, some might need to reload the page and search for something. I know I can separate the retry logic to be reused, but with time is it going to become a maintenance nightmare? Is there a more refined way to test asynchronous behaviors?

Comment: Writing tests and developing the system are not separate activities. Being able to be tested automatically is a often ignored but essential non-functional requirement. So this sounds like a good reason to make email sending effectively instantaneous. This ofcourse also has other benefits.

Comment: I would love it, but i'm afraid that's not an option considering how big the system is, we already discussed and just thought of it as "a challenge" for the automated tests.

Comment: I'm thinking this might be a case where adding "sleep" is ok, i know it is a bad practice when you need to wait for an element to load, since we have more precise and efficient ways to do it, but when we talk about operations that run in the background, there is no way of asserting it except waiting and trying again (with a delicate relation of wait time and max number of retries), it is the nature of asynchronous behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following :

1. check that the async task creation is called `expect().to receive().with()`
2. call the async tack in the test
3. do some additional checks

Testing that async tasks are actually executed when they are created should be done seperaltly. In these test you migh need to use `sleep`

It will allow you to have clean and fast functionnal tests